# List database entry with ID in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, each

I found it difficult to title this question. It is easier if you see the situation:

by having this in my view

```
<% @scrapbook.scrapbook_entries.each do |d|%>

  <%= d.recipe_id %>

<% end %>
```

I am given a list of recipe id's (3 of them) that are in the scrapbook_entries database table.

```
358 358 341
```

What I want to do is use these ID's and search the recipe table for all the information linked to them.

```
E.g. Display @recipe.name with ID 358.
```

Is there an easy way to do this in the view? Let me know if I am not making sense

Comment: see how delegates used in rails http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, you can immediately put something like

```
= d.recipe.name
```

Behind the scenes, this will use your recipe id to look up the correct record, then take the name atttribute of this record

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<% @scrapbook.scrapbook_entries.each do |d|%>

  <%= d.recipe_id %>
  <%= d.recipe ? d.recipe.name : '' %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the relationship defined on the `ScrapbookEntry` model you can get the recipe instance and access any of its attributes.

```
class ScrapbookEntry < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :recipe

end
```

```
<% @scrapbook.scrapbook_entries.each do |d|%>

  <%= d.recipe.name %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a delegate in your scrabook_entry

```
delegate :name, :to => :recipe
```

than in your view

```
d.name
```